# Unable to Authorize an Org in VSCode

Tags: salesforcedx-cli, vs-code

I'm unable to **Authorize an Org** from **VSCode**.

I'm getting the following error.

```
Starting SFDX: Authorize an Org

16:39:55.121 sfdx force:auth:web:login --setalias <org-name> --instanceurl https://login.salesforce.com --setdefaultusername
16:39:55.125 sfdx force:auth:web:login --setalias <org-name> --instanceurl https://login.salesforce.com --setdefaultusername
 Salesforce CLI is not installed. Install it from https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/sfdxcli
```

I do have the Salesforce CLI installed and it has been added in the path; I've added the following line in my `.bashrc`

```
PATH="~/Workspace/sfdx/bin:$PATH"
```

I can directly run `sfdx` from the terminal.

```
$ sfdx --version
sfdx-cli/7.132.0 linux-x64 node-v16.13.1
```

My OS is **Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue by opening VSCode directly from my project folder as follows.

```
$ code .
```

And then, from the integrated terminal, I ran the following command.

```
sfdx force:auth:web:login --setalias <org-name> --instanceurl https://login.salesforce.com --setdefaultusername
```

Not sure if this is the correct way but it fixed the issue.

---

**Update #1**

Looks like the issue was with the `PATH` variable. Once I set it to the absolute path of `sfdx`, it started to work.

```
PATH="/home/bilesh/Workspace/sfdx/bin:$PATH"
```

VSCode was giving issues if I used `~`.

Now, `SFDX: Authorize an Org` command is working as expected.