# SFDX: Execute SOQL Query failed to run

Tags: soql, salesforcedx-cli, vs-code

Unable to run SOQL queries on VSCode. I'm getting the following error.

```
Starting SFDX: Execute SOQL Query...

19:33:27.886 sfdx force:data:soql:query --query  SELECT Id, Name FROM Account
19:33:27.888 sfdx force:data:soql:query --query  SELECT Id, Name FROM Account
 Salesforce CLI is not installed. Install it from https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/sfdxcli
```

But if I run the above command directly from the integrated terminal, it executes.

```
$ sfdx force:data:soql:query --query "SELECT Id, Name FROM Account"
ID                  NAME
──────────────────  ───────────────────────────────────
0015f00000HkEKZAA3  Sample Account for Entitlements
0015f00000I8QV5AAN  GenePoint
0015f00000I8QV3AAN  United Oil & Gas, UK
0015f00000I8QV4AAN  United Oil & Gas, Singapore
0015f00000I8QUvAAN  Edge Communications
0015f00000I8QUwAAN  Burlington Textiles Corp of America
0015f00000I8QUxAAN  Pyramid Construction Inc.
0015f00000I8QUyAAN  Dickenson plc
0015f00000I8QUzAAN  Grand Hotels & Resorts Ltd
0015f00000I8QV1AAN  Express Logistics and Transport
0015f00000I8QV2AAN  University of Arizona
0015f00000I8QV0AAN  United Oil & Gas Corp.
0015f00000I8QV6AAN  sForce
Total number of records retrieved: 13.
Querying Data... done
```

I faced a similar issue when Authorizing the Org. Refer to: [Unable to Authorize an Org in VSCode](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/366542/unable-to-authorize-an-org-in-vscode)

My OS is **Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the issue was with the `PATH` variable. Once I set it to the absolute path of `sfdx`, it started to work.

```
PATH="/home/bilesh/Workspace/sfdx/bin:$PATH"
```

VSCode was giving issues if I used `~`.

Now, the `SFDX: Execute SOQL Query...` command is working as expected.

```
Starting SFDX: Execute SOQL Query...

21:58:10.427 sfdx force:data:soql:query --query  SELECT Id, Name FROM Account
Querying Data... done
ID                  NAME
──────────────────  ───────────────────────────────────
0015f00000HkEKZAA3  Sample Account for Entitlements
0015f00000I8QV5AAN  GenePoint
0015f00000I8QV3AAN  United Oil & Gas, UK
0015f00000I8QV4AAN  United Oil & Gas, Singapore
0015f00000I8QUvAAN  Edge Communications
0015f00000I8QUwAAN  Burlington Textiles Corp of America
0015f00000I8QUxAAN  Pyramid Construction Inc.
0015f00000I8QUyAAN  Dickenson plc
0015f00000I8QUzAAN  Grand Hotels & Resorts Ltd
0015f00000I8QV1AAN  Express Logistics and Transport
0015f00000I8QV2AAN  University of Arizona
0015f00000I8QV0AAN  United Oil & Gas Corp.
0015f00000I8QV6AAN  sForce
Total number of records retrieved: 13.
21:58:11.702 sfdx force:data:soql:query --query  SELECT Id, Name FROM Account
 ended with exit code 0
```